# Migration .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 Integration test from Body always null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to migrate my API and integration test from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1.
After migration and breaching Microsoft changes adjustment considering all works fine for API prj.
I tried it by postman.

At this point i try to migrate my integration test project, but after the migration all http calls with [FromBody] parameters go in error because fromBody parameters are always null.

Here some more info:

.NET Core 2.2 code:

```
        IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder = Program.CreateBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment(TestEnvironmentName.Get(inMemory: true))
            .ConfigureEntityFrameworkForTesting(fixture);
        _server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);

        var client = _server.CreateClient();
        _client = new FluentClient("http://a", client);
        _client.SetHttpErrorAsException(false);

        _testHost = TestHostBuilder.Create()
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTestServiceBus(_server.Host.Services))
            .Build();
        _testHost.Run();
```

.NET Core 3.1 code:

```
               var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHost =>
               {
                   // Add TestServer
                   webHost.UseTestServer();
                   webHost.UseEnvironment(HostTestEnvironmentName.Get(inMemory: true))
                        .ConfigureEntityFrameworkForTesting(fixture)
                        .UseStartup<Startup>();
               });

                var host = hostBuilder.Start();
                var client = host.GetTestClient();

                _client = new FluentClient("http://a", client);

                _server = host.GetTestServer();
```

I already:

- Check if https client used by tests contains "ContentType" as json.
- Trying to remove fluent client and use "System.Net.Http.HttpClient".

Now my suspicious are on this message that i found when call host.GetTestServer(). But it's not a real error, it doesn't break my runtime, i just see it with quick watch on _server variable.

Error message: "The TestServer constructor was not called with a IWebHostBuilder so IWebHost is not available." [QuickWatchImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oBuL.png)

I'm not very sure it's related to my issue my i'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the absense of any other answers, I'll take a swing at this and you decide if it is good for one:

https://developpaper.com/asp-net-core-uses-xunit-for-host-level-network-integration-testing/

In the above link I found my magic sauce for the same error message ("The TestServer constructor was not called with a IWebHostBuilder so IWebHost is not available.").

What I had to do was change code that newed up an IHost (which is what we're supposed to do for 3.0+) over for the 2.x IWebHost.

Full disclosure: I'm completely new to integration testing and am building my very first one today. But this code did the trick:

```
// no dice -- "The TestServer constructor was not called with a IWebHostBuilder...
// var hostBuilder = Your.App.Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0], config);
// using var system = new SystemUnderTest(hostBuilder);

// this seems to be the way forward
var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<<Your.App.Startup>()
    .UseConfiguration(config);
using var system = new SystemUnderTest(webHostBuilder);
```

Anyway, that's where I'm at now. Seems I may be through the worst of it.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however WebHostBuilder is meant to be deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder

Comment: And now we're on 5.x / 6.x LOL... My setup has diverged quite a bit since I wrote here last. Here's hoping yours has too, and that this question is no longer relevant...

Comment: Well, we only started our migration from 2.2 to 3.0, so still kind of relevant :) In the end, we ended up using the WebApplicationFactory and ensuring our project file had <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">